# status: -1: There was an error with the request: no protocol:

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to do an HTTP request on an android emulator, I built with ionic and compiled with capacitor.

I'm using the `HTTP` module from `@ionic-native/http/ngx`. I have a per-existing interceptor that I used when I was making requests using the `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`. This is what that interceptor looks like:

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  protected apiUri = environment.API_URL;
  constructor(
      private authSvc: AuthService,
      private toastCtrl: ToastController
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url = this.apiUri + req.url;
    const token = this.authSvc.getStorageToken();
    if (token) {
      req = req.clone({
        url,
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          return event;
        }),
        catchError( (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          let errMessage =  err.error.message;
          if (err.error.title) {
            errMessage = err.error.title;
          }
          if (!errMessage) {
            errMessage = err.error;
          }
          this.presentToast(err.status, errMessage);
          return throwError(err);
        })
    );
  }
  async presentToast(status: number, message: string) {
    const toast = await this.toastCtrl.create({
      message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await toast.present();
  }
}
```

My auth-service:

```
   /* service request to get a toke */
    getAuthToken(model: IGetTokenModel) {
        return this.http.post('/user/token', model, {});
      }
```

The `environment.API_URL` is the url to my API on my local machine.

I'm guessing the `no protocol` means I'm posting data to `/user/auth` instead of the full which includes the hostname. But I'm not sure of this. However, if that were the case, how would I refactor my interceptor so that it works as expected with the `@ionic-native/http/ngx`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally have this sorted. I was pointing to localhost inside the emulator. Turns out that requests made inside the emulator have to point to `http://10.0.2.2:PORT`.

I suppose `localhost` in a sense still point to the emulator itself.